# How can i remove the translate links on html print reports in odoo8

Tags: python, xml, odoo, qweb

the links of languages and the one of add language,
i did try disable the translations but it stills show the links.any help?

similar issue
https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/help-1/question/remove-the-language-information-when-i-print-a-qweb-invoice-report-64228

Answer (score -3, accepted):

solved i went to `UI/views/layout.xml` and edited it

Answer (score -1):

Please try the below code.

[image]

```
ul.nomargin li.dropdown {
        display: none;
    }
```